# How to rank only duplicated rows and without Nan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with data:

```
   Col1
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   2.0
4   3.0
5   4.0
6   NaN
```

How can I rank **only** duplicated values (without taking into account NaN as well)?
My current output is where unfortunately unique values are ranked as well:

```
   Col1   Rn
0   1.0  1.0
1   1.0  2.0
2   1.0  3.0
3   2.0  1.0
4   3.0  1.0
5   4.0  1.0
6   NaN  NaN
```

The output I need is:

```
   Col1   Rn
0   1.0  1.0
1   1.0  2.0
2   1.0  3.0
3   2.0  NaN
4   3.0  NaN
5   4.0  NaN
6   NaN  NaN
```

Example of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1],
                   [1],
                   [1],
                   [2],
                   [3],
                   [4],
                   [np.NaN]], columns=['Col1'])
print(df)


# Adding row_number for each pair:
df['Rn'] = df[df['Col1'].notnull()].groupby('Col1')['Col1'].rank(method="first", ascending=True)
print(df)

# I managed to select only necessary rows for mask, but how can I apply it along with groupby?:
m = df.dropna().loc[df['Col1'].duplicated(keep=False)]
print(m)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
m = df['Col1'].duplicated(keep=False)
df['Rn'] = df[m].groupby('Col1')['Col1'].rank(method="first", ascending=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Col1   Rn
0   1.0  1.0
1   1.0  2.0
2   1.0  3.0
3   2.0  NaN
4   3.0  NaN
5   4.0  NaN
6   NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) values and only compute the [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) for those:

```
# identify duplicated rows
m = df['Col1'].duplicated(keep=False)

# compute the rank only for those
df['Rn'] = df.loc[m, 'Col1'].rank(method='first', ascending=True)
```

Note thank if you want to increment a count of the duplicates, you can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
m = df['Col1'].duplicated(keep=False)

df['Rn'] = df.loc[m, ['Col1']].groupby('Col1').cumcount().add(1)
```

Output:

```
   Col1   Rn
0   1.0  1.0
1   1.0  2.0
2   1.0  3.0
3   2.0  NaN
4   3.0  NaN
5   4.0  NaN
6   NaN  NaN
```